# abp problem after updating devexpress from 21.1.4 to 21.2.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, asp.net-boilerplate

i have an asp.net zero project.
i've used devexpress 21.1.4 and everything was fine, after updating devexpress to 21.2.5 by project converter extension i got this error :
**component for supporting the service Abp.AspNetCore.Configuration.AbpAspNetCoreConfiguration was found** 
int this lines of startup:

`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
var ops = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions>().Value;
}`

i used
 `servises.AddTransient<AbpAspNetCoreConfiguration>`  in ConfigureServices method but it didnt work fine.
what should i do to resolve this error?
thank for your time.

Comment: Did you read following : https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3703

Comment: @jdweng thanks for response. yes i tried all answers and none of them worked.